# Using payload of action on ActionsSubject subscription on NGRX

Tags: angular, observable, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-entity

I got the old and bad `Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'Action` doing this actions subscription:

Since is a Creation Action, I need the payload to checkout the `userId` of the recently created User and navigate to `/users/userId`

BTW: I'm following [this really nice tutorial](https://netbasal.com/listening-for-actions-in-ngrx-store-a699206d2210)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sample',
  templateUrl: 'sample.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
  subs = new Subscription();

  constructor(private actionsSubject: ActionsSubject) {
    this.subs = actionsSubject.subscribe(action => {
      if (action.type === actions.CREATE_USER_SUCCESS) {
        console.log(action.payload);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at ActionsSubject class declaration, you will notice that when you subscribe to it, you are supposed to get objects of class `Action`, defined like so:

```
export interface Action {
  type: string;
}
```

As you can see, there is simply no `payload` here. That means that you need to tell TypeScript that inside the if you expect some object that is typed more stricly.

I would try (assuming that your Action class is named CreateUserSuccessAction):

```
this.subs = actionsSubject.subscribe((action: Action) => {
  if (action.type === actions.CREATE_USER_SUCCESS) {
    let createUserAction: CreateUserSuccessAction = action as CreateUserSuccessAction;  
    console.log(action.payload);
  }
});
```

or better (assuming you use RxJS 6):

```
this.subs = actionsSubject.pipe(
  filter((action: Action) => action.type === actions.CREATE_USER_SUCCESS)
).subscribe((action: CreateUserSuccessAction) => {
  console.log(action.payload);
});
```

Hope that helps!